# Howto open IndexedDB just once with jquery promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexeddb, promise

I am using Jquery promises to handle opening of an indexedDB to store files and then read and write files to it (am using these for the first time). As any of the functions can be called in any order I always call the function to open the DB first before attempting the operation, the code is as below,

```
var DatabaseSingleton = (function () {
        var openDbPromise = $.Deferred();
        var openDb = function() {
            var db;
            var request = window.indexedDB.open("myDb", 2);

            request.onerror = function(event) {
                console.error('Error opening indexedDB connection.');
                openDbPromise.reject();
            }
            request.onsuccess = function(event) {
                console.log('db opened', request.result);
                db = request.result;
                db.onerror = function(event) {
                    console.error("Database error: " + event.target.error.name);
                };
                openDbPromise.resolve(db);
            }
            request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
                console.log('upgrading the idb', event.target.result);
                db = event.target.result;
                // create a store for the files
                db.createObjectStore("fileInfo", { keyPath: "name" }).createIndex("name", "name", { unique: false });
            };

            return openDbPromise.promise();
        };

    return {
        // retrive a list of all files in the DB
        getFilesList: function() {
            var filesPromise = $.Deferred();
            openDb().then(function(db) {
                            ...
            });
            return filesPromise.promise();
        },

        // retrieve metainfo of the file specified by its fileName
        getFileinfo: function (fileName) {
            var getInfoPromise = $.Deferred();
            openDb().then(function(db) {
                            ...
            });
            return getInfoPromise.promise();
        },
}) ();
```

However with this I notice the 'db opened' being displayed every time any of the functions are called. Is there a better way to make sure that it is only being opened once and then just resolved for succeeding calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands, `var request = window.indexedDB.open("myDb", 2);` etc is executed unconditionally every time `openDb()` is called.

The most straightforward approach is to introduce an `if(...){}` clause, to ensure that `var request = window.indexedDB.open("myDb", 2);` etc is only executed when a successful `request` (and hence `db`) has not been established (or is not in the process of being established).

Try this :

```
var DatabaseSingleton = (function () {
    var openDbDeferred;
    var openDb = function() {
        if(!openDbDeferred || openDbDeferred.isRejected()) {
            openDbDeferred = $.Deferred();
            var db;
            var request = window.indexedDB.open("myDb", 2);
            request.onsuccess = function(event) {
                console.log('db opened', request.result);
                db = request.result;
                db.onerror = function(event) {
                    console.error("Database error: " + event.target.error.name);
                };
                openDbDeferred.resolve(db);
            };
            request.onerror = function(event) {
                console.error('Error opening indexedDB connection.');
                openDbDeferred.reject();
            };
            request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
                console.log('upgrading the idb', event.target.result);
                db = event.target.result;
                // create a store for the files
                db.createObjectStore("fileInfo", { keyPath: "name" }).createIndex("name", "name", { unique: false });
            };
        }
        return openDbDeferred.promise();
    };
    return {
        //retrive a list of all files in the DB
        getFilesList: function() {
            return openDb().then(function(db) {
                ...
            });
        },
        //retrieve metainfo of the file specified by its fileName
        getFileinfo: function(fileName) {
            return openDb().then(function(db) {
                ...
            });
        }
    };
}) ();
```

If you don't want `openDb()` to keep trying after previous failure, then change :

```
if(!openDbDeferred || openDbDeferred.isRejected()) {
```

to :

```
if(!openDbDeferred) {
```

Answer (score 1):

I've written a small jquery plugin (still very alpha) that does this:

https://github.com/ameyms/jquery-indexeddb

And I've tried to keep the API super simple:

```js
//Define and initialize an IndexedDB ...
var db = $.idb({
                    name:'foobar', 
                    version: 2,
                    drop: stores_to_be_deleted,
                    stores:list_of_stores
                });

// ... Add objects to a store
db.put(items, 'into_store').done(onsuccess);

//.. And delete objects from a store
db.remove('from_store', conditionFunc).done(onremoval);

//.. And not to forget fetching objects from a store
db.select('from_my_store', conditionFunc).done(function (items){

    console.log(items)
});
```

Hope you like it!

Answer (score 0):

The design is not robust in practice, because you cannot reliably use the database connection. It can be blocked at any time by other connection. Without closing the connection, you will find infrequently that, a promise never resolve due to race condition among connections. On the other hand, if you close the connection, how will consumer know the connection is closed.

Comment: Hmm... what would be the best way to achieve this in that case?